# MySql order multiple columns consider multiple

Tags: mysql

```
  id  | p_id   
--------------------------
  1   | 0
  2   | 0    
  3   | 1        
  4   | 2 
  5   | 0
  6   | 7    
  7   | 1        
  8   | 0
```

This is above table data's, if i give

```
SELECT * from tablename order by `id` asc
```

it will bring the above result set

But my use case is i need to sort by both the id and p_id in a different way (i.e) i need to get result set by like below

```
          id  | p_id   
    --------------------------
          1   | 0
          3   | 1    
          7   | 1
          6   | 7
          2   | 0  
          4   | 2 
          5   | 0        
          8   | 0
```

let me explain briefly about that, `p_id` value `1` should be the next to the `id` `1` and that is arranged like above, it clearly show that `p_id` `1` and `p_id` `2` is next to the `id` `1` and `2` respectively and make sure that `id` `7` in order and id `6` next to id `7`

Comment: Explain more the criterion of sorting

Comment: @1000111 i explained now clearly

Comment: Hi i explained now with neat description

Comment: The result set does not match the rules?

Comment: @P.Salmon why it is clearly mention that `p_id` should present next to `id`

Comment: Argh. misunderstood "p_id value 1 should be the next to the id 1" I thought you meant literally 1.

Comment: @P.Salmon p_id value 1 should be the next to the id 1 yes but if p_id having more 1 it should order in asc

Comment: Is there some sort of relationship between ids 1,3,7,6 that you haven't mentioned in your question? Same question for ids 2,4,5,8.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly , you want the order to be -> If `P_id=0` then to order by `ID` , else, order by p_id.

You can achieve this by conditional ordering using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.pid = 0 
              THEN t.id
              ELSE t.p_id
         END ASC,
         t.id
```

This should return you your expected results.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but it fails when id is 2 and then corresponding p_id is 4

Comment: I don't understand, this query should output the same results as in your example. , `2,4` will be ordered after `2,0` @SelvaGanapathi

Comment: yeah it satisfied for that use, but it fails for the `6,7`, it should present after the `7,1`. @sagi

Comment: please make sure that `id` should present after the `p_id`

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the relationship between the id's and since the 2 id blocks have different sort requirements you also need a helper column and a subquery.

```
create table t (id int, pid int)
insert into t    
values
(  1   , 0),
(  2   , 0),   
(  3   , 1),        
(  4   , 2), 
(  5   , 0),
(  6   , 7),    
(  7   , 1),        
(  8   , 0)

select  s.id,s.pid 
        from
(
select case
        when t.id in (1,3,7,6) then 1
        else 2
        end  as ac 
        ,
        case 
        when t.id in (1,3,7,6) then pid
        else id
        end  as sortcol 
        ,
        t.*
from    t 
) s
order   by s.ac,s.sortcol
```

Result

```
id  pid
1   0
3   1
7   1
6   7
2   0
4   2
5   0
8   0
```

Comment: this will have laks of id in that table and i cant give static number's

Comment: Didn't think you could, but to reiterate the sort criteria for the 2 id blocks are different. Without a relationship between ids in id blocks then I don't believe your requirement is achievable.